# Containers present on multiple host unable to communicate with each other

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We have cluster of two nodes, each hosting 5 containers each. Both host are able to `ping` each other and host are able to ping their containers too.

Now I need to communicate between the two containers residing on two different hosts. In this case ping is failing.

Here is how my network looks like:

```
 [C-1] <->[C-2:172.18.0.4]                      [C-1:172.18.0.4] <-> [C-2]    
     |                                               |
     |                                               |
[host1:10.1.10.160]   <-----ping works -----> [host2: 10.1.10.161]
```

How can I ping between `C2` of host1 and `C1` of host2? 
Note: I tried using overlay networks but I need to use `docker-compose up` and I cannot use individual `docker run` command for all containers.

Any suggestions on how to achieve the results?